# How to rise Usererror based on selection in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have inherited a the purchase.order and added a selection field(fixed,percentage) and a float field. When i select the percentage, the float value should not be greater than 100 and should throw an error.

How can I achieve this?

This is my code

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = "purchase.order"
_description="Purchase the products"

discount=fields.Selection([('fixed','fixed Price'),('percentage','Percentage')],string="Discount")
amount=fields.Float("Amount")

@api.multi
@api.constrains('amount')
def Limited(self):
    if self.discount=='percentage'and self.amount > 100:
        raise UserError(_('Please enter proper amount'))
```

Comment: Your code seems good to me. Can you edit your question with current output ?

Comment: @Odedra This shows one time error. Suggest me any other method

Comment: You can go with _On change_ method.

Comment: Can you edit and send me the code please @Odedra

Comment: You should try it your self. That's will help you next time rather to ask/send for code.

Comment: Done sir @ Odedra

Comment: And please look at another question I have asked. I am having a big headache on how to do it @Odedra

Answer (score 1):

*You can try this code:*

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('amount')
def Limited(self):
    if self.discount=='percentage' and self.amount > 100:
        raise UserError(_('Please enter proper amount'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code.

```py
@api.onchange('amount','discount')
def onchange_amount_discount(self):
    if self.discount=='percentage' and self.amount > 100:
        raise UserError(_('Please enter proper amount')
```

NOTE:

Onchange method will fire when you update *amount* or *discount* field.

Answer (score -1):

constrains and validations errors are always helpful.

Comment: Can you provide an example in code, so the answer can be specific?